# Validating a cell and displaying a balloon tool tip for datagridview in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview, tooltip

I have a datagridview in my form and I would like to perform validation for a row each time the user enters a value to some cell.

I've tried to use RowValidating event but it has some issues after setting e.Canel to true:

- The user is able to exit the edit mode and edit other rows by simply clicking on another cell on the same row, or by pressing TAB or ENTER after typing the cell's value.
- When e.Canel == true the whole form seems to be stuck, which is a good thing. However, if the user tries to close the form (by pressing the close button on the left corner) only the outer border of the window disappears and the rest of the controls in the forms remain "floating" around (still stuck).

So I was wondering maybe there's another event more suitable to my needs? or any ideas of how to fix the above issues?

Given that I have a way of freezing the edit of a row, I would also like to display an error balloon tool tip next to the relevant row specifying what's wrong.
I figured that in order to do that, I must set the ShowCellToolTips property of my dataGridView to false. However, my rows might contain a lot of data and thus I would like the option of showing the tool tips when the mouse hovers over a cell. 
Do I have a way to show the balloon tool tip without setting ShowCellToolTips to false?

One last thing - I would prefer that the balloon tool tip would point up, like the tool tip that is shown when you insert illegal character while trying to rename a file. It seems that the default balloon tool tip points down, how can I change it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Implement handlers for the DataGridView control's CellValidating and CellEndEdit events.

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender,
    DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    // Validate the CompanyName entry by disallowing empty strings.
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "CompanyName")
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.FormattedValue.ToString()))
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText =
                "Company Name must not be empty";
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}

void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // Clear the row error in case the user presses ESC.   
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].ErrorText = String.Empty;
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ykdxa0bc(v=vs.80).aspx